# Selecting a sheet from the value in a cell

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to select a sheet based on the value in the cell. For example

```
  Col_1      Col_2      Col_3

  gor         100        jan
  mack        60         jan
  john        40         mar---->this data
  ..... So on
```

Here am checking for persons who have below 50 hours and if they have 50 hours then i have to go to that sheet and mark them to represent them.
here john has below 50 hours then i have to get the sheet name from the col_3 that's here March. I have to goto that mar sheet and mark them.   My question is that. Is it possible to select or get a sheet name based on the value in a cell.

Comment: If you know the row/col for that cell then you can use `Range(...).Value` to get the value in the cell, and yes, use that to activate another sheet, where `...` is the cell location, "C4" for example. You can also use `Cells(row,col).Value` as well.

Comment: `ws = Worksheets(Worksheets("Report").Range("H" & intRow1).Value).Activate`

Comment: @Ryan J This is what i did so far but returning error cause it is taking only the date eg.. The sheet Name is Mar-15 and that is what is on the cell but it is only getting the data as if in (13/3/15) but there is no sheet named like it. There is only mar-15. And i want it to take as it is. Any suggesion?

Answer (score 1):

If your cell value is a date string, you can use `Format` to put it in the string format you require. For example, if your cell contains "3/15/15", you can turn this into the sheet name "Mar-15" using the code below:

```
Dim dateVal As String
' assume this is your active sheet
Worksheets(1).Activate

' for simplicity, just set a date
Cells(1, 1).Value = "3/15/15"

' read the date from the cell and format to get month name
dateVal = Format(Cells(1, 1).Value, "mmm-YY")
MsgBox ("Month from Date: " & dateVal)
```

Output shows:

[image]

Note that you may need to adjust for the format of your date, as I'm working with a US-English format, but the concept is to format what the value in the cell contains into what you want.

Answer (score 0):

About this line
ws = Worksheets(Worksheets("Report").Range("H" & intRow1).Value).Activate –

When you want to select or activate any value from particular sheet then those sheet must be activate o/w it gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try use the below code. It is written for activecell only but can be extended for range of cell.

```
Dim sname As String

If ActiveCell.Value < 50 Then
    sname = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value & "-" & "15"
    Sheets(sname).Select

End If
```